# Cucumber installation "uninitialized constant Logger::Formatter (NameError)"

Tags: rubygems, cucumber

Cucumber installation problem, help needed with troubleshooting.

I am pretty sure this problem is not directly related to cucumber. However, it prevents me from installing cucumber. I hope that you might have ideas to help me troubleshoot.

```
$ bundle exec cucumber --version

/Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:188:in `<class:Configuration>': uninitialized constant Logger::Formatter (NameError)
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:12:in `<module:Cli>'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:7:in `<module:Cucumber>'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/bin/cucumber:7:in `require'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/gems/cucumber-2.0.0.rc.4/bin/cucumber:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Tried with latest release `1.3.19` but I get same error on `1.3.18` and `2.0.0.rc.4`. Same error

Tried running directly as `cucumber --version´, and also tried to run`bundle exec cucumber --version` as the example above. Same error.

Tried on `ruby 2.0.0` as the example above. Also tried with `2.1.5` and `2.2.0` and `2.2.0`. Same error

Tried as a separate gemset (as example above). Also tried as global gemset, and tried as part of the project. In the example above, I deleted all other gems from `Gemfile`, so the gemset is cleaned from everything not related to cucumber.

There are no errors during the install process (using `bundle install`).

Since the problem is present in all cucumber versions and ruby versions I tried, I don't suspect cucumber itself to be the problem. There must be something else I am missing?

I use RVM, as you can probably see, and here is the result of my `gem environment`:

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jesper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jesper/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jesper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard
     - /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@vcard/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/vertx/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/springboot/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/lazybones/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/jbake/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/groovyserv/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/groovy/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/griffon/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/grails/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/gradle/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/glide/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/gaiden/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/crash/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.gvm/asciidoctorj/current/bin
     - /Users/jesper/.dotfiles/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/jesper/instantclient_11_2
```

Do you have suggestions as to

- how can I troubleshoot my installation?
- what could cause the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Thanks to Steven Tooke in the Copenhagen Ruby Brigade mailing list, the problem was a local `logger.rb`  file in my local code. Details available here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/copenhagen-ruby-user-group/FNXAs8EW8LY